# How to paraphrase this sentence "others serve the state chiefly with their heads..."?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Others, as most legislators, politicians, lawyers, ministers, and
>   office-holders, serve the state chiefly with their heads; and, as they
>   rarely make any moral distinctions, they are as likely to serve the
>   devil, **without intending it**, as God.

How to paraphrase this sentence?

1. Does "without intending it" mean "without thinking of it" and what does "it" refer to?

   I found a sentence from the Bible "For they intended evil against thee: they imagined a mischievous device, which they are not able to perform", I'm not sure if "it" refers to evil/devil.
2. "serve the state with...",does it mean "use...to serve the state"?

Comment: It means they don't intend to serve the devil, but wind up doing so.

Comment: @Robusto If they serve the devil, they didn't realize it's devil?

Comment: No. It means that by serving the state "chiefly with their heads," and not making any **moral** distinctions, they may serve the devil (i.e., perform evil) without that being their intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote comes from the King James version of *Psalm 21:11*

> For they intended evil against thee: they imagined a mischievous device, which they are not able to perform.

It might be clearer if you used [another translation](http://biblehub.com/psalms/21-11.htm)

> *New International Verion* - Though they plot evil against you and devise wicked schemes, they cannot succeed
>
> *English Standard Version* - Though they plan evil against you, though they devise mischief, they will not succeed.

In your selection

> they are as likely to serve the devil, without intending it, as God.

*It* refers to "their likeliness to serve the devil", that "they will serve the devil without meaning to serve the devil", the reason why is because " they rarely make any moral distinctions".